# How much flex can a wall have that supports tile?

Tags: framing, tile, construction, lumber

I have a short divider wall in my bathroom that separates the shower from the rest of the bathroom.  Originally the wall was made of 2x2 wood.  Topdown image showing the wall in question colored blue:

[image: Here's a topdown view with the wall]

I want to tile the shower, and I'm worried about the flimsiness of that wall, but there isn't room to put in 2x4s because of the door.   So I tried reframing the wall using 3x4s turned sideways (think of it as a 4x3?) in the hopes that would be strong enough at 2.5" wide instead of the 1.5" framing of the 2x2s.  The wall is 8.75' tall.

When it was done, I was saddened to see that it still had considerably more flex than a proper 2x4 - and now I'm worried that I'm going to tile up the up the entire shower and the flex of that wall is going to start to crack the mortar and the tile wall will fail.

So the question comes down to - how much of the flex is handled by the mortar and how much is expected to be handled by the wall framing?  Is the wall frame mostly for holding the weight of the tile/mortar?

Or really the question is - if I tile this, is it just going to start to crack and ruin all my plans?

Comment: backer board, crack isolation membrane, and specifically mastic for walls, not thinset. "a short divider wall" the whole thing wiggles? Then it'll just crack at the floor like it will everywhere else. Defection is how far you can get the members to bow, and then crack individual grout lines, not push the whole assembly which is fine because they say that line should be caulk anyway. Put some extra screws into the floor runner. And if it's flying between a stud cavity, put some blocking to screw it to the wall.

Comment: If it's really that bad, and that may be used as a grab bar: a lateral buttress at a 45 to the wall. But it has to be like 6' tall and when you're dealing with 12' ceilings (yours is floor to ceiling so it's fine). Naked framing is quite flexible, especially 2x4s sideways. But after you attach *concrete* backer board with screws *every 6~8 inches*, put a layer of CIM, mastic, and then tile... it will stiffen considerably. Use a hinge doorstop, not a bumper; door hitting it is how it's going to crack.

Comment: How big are the tiles?

Comment: Most of them are 4x10 and we're planning on doing one line of 8x8

Answer (score 2):

If the wood is too bendy use stiffer wood, if it's still too bendy, use metal.

Using rectangular hollow steel or aluminium tube as the end stud  should cure the problem.  but going to a harder grade of wood may be sufficient.

Another option may be to use a scaffold plank as your end stud, that should have sufficient stiffness

Answer (score 1):

The usual standard for ceramic tile is l/360. For stone the recommendations are as little as half that. Most material will be focussed on floor deflection, but the tile adhesion issue is no different for walls deflecting, it's just that people don't usually walk on walls. But if the wall bends when leaned against, the bend should be less than l/360, or 0.292 inches for a 8.75 foot wall.

Comment: Is that the deflection *with* the backer board, or just for the framing itself?

And all the deflection calculators seem to be for 4", 6", 8" deep lumber - does anyone know where I can calculate deflection for 3" deep lumber?  And for how much "weight" should I be basing this on?

Comment: Or a clearer question "if the wall bends when leaned against" - how much leaning are we talking about here?  I feel like to be on the safe side I should be pushing pretty hard on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Could you purchase a glass divider? (Not a door, but a static panel.)

Alternatively, would the PVC panel work instead of tiles? That would be very flexible, and can be gotten in many different patterns.

Comment: We definitely don't want PVC.  The glass divider was something we considered, but it would only be for the portion of that wall that comes into the bathroom (see the diagram) and we thought that would be a bit strange to have part of the wall tile and part glass.